# Ajax request with type 'POST' not working, only with 'GET'

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, post

I'm trying to send and ajax post request to my springboot mvc controller, but with no success. I've looked a number of similar topics, tried the given solutions, but with no success at all.
If I change the request type to GET, it triggers the controller endpoint.

The endpoint function is not even being triggered in the controller. It is showing only the following error in browser console: **jquery-3.4.1.js:9837 POST http://localhost:8080/rede-credenciada 500**

I made the same request with postman and it gives the following error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-07-09T17:46:20.920+0000",
    "status": 999,
    "error": "None",
    "message": "No message available"
}
```

**Note: It only happens with POST request, if I change to GET, it works fine. The request is "listened" by the controller.**

Here is my ajax request:

```
const json = {
    idGrupoProcedimento: 0,
    idTipoEspecialidade: $("#especialidade").val(),
    uf: $("#estado").val(),
    codCidade: $("#cidade").val()
}

const jsonString = JSON.stringify(json);

$.ajax({
    url: "/rede-credenciada",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "application/json",
    data: jsonString,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
});
```

Here, my endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rede-credenciada", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public RedeCredenciadaResponse buscaRedeCredenciadaPorFiltro(@RequestBody RedeCredenciadaRequest request) {
        
    ... some logic
    
    RedeCredenciadaResponse redeCredenciada = new RedeCredenciadaResponse();
    
    redeCredenciada.setPessoasFisicas(pessoas);
    redeCredenciada.setEmpresas(empresas);
    
    return redeCredenciada;
}
```

And here is my wrapper class:

```
public class RedeCredenciadaRequest {

private int idGrupoProcedimento;

private int idTipoEspecialidade;

private String uf;

private String codCidade;

public int getIdGrupoProcedimento() {
    return idGrupoProcedimento;
}

public void setIdGrupoProcedimento(int idGrupoProcedimento) {
    this.idGrupoProcedimento = idGrupoProcedimento;
}

public int  getIdTipoEspecialidade() {
    return idTipoEspecialidade;
}

public void setIdTipoEspecialidade(int idTipoEspecialidade) {
    this.idTipoEspecialidade = idTipoEspecialidade;
}

public String getUf() {
    return uf;
}

public void setUf(String uf) {
    this.uf = uf;
}

public String getCodCidade() {
    return codCidade;
}

public void setCodCidade(String cidade) {
    this.codCidade = cidade;
}
```

[image]
The error:

Comment: Your server is printing error messages on its console output. Post them.

Comment: Do you mean in eclipse console?

Comment: 500 means Server Side Error, Please check the Logs in your Back-end application

Comment: That's the problem, no logs at all in my back-end application!!!

Comment: Wherever the server's standard output is, which will usually be the Eclipse console if you're running it inside Eclipse.

Comment: I'm running in eclipse, and it is exactly what I said. No logs at all in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ajax request you are using `dataType:'application/json'`, According to [jQuery’s Ajax-Related Methods](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods/) Description

```
// The type of data we expect back
dataType : "json",
```

Value of `dataType` shoud be *json*, or *xml*, or *html*, etc.